# Why is "CA"["CA"] true?

Tags: ruby

I am working with the "any?" method in a block. The snippet is looking for the string "CA" in the string (split) **check**:

```
region="CA"
check="AU,US,UK,CA,ZA"
if check.split(',').any? { |r| region[r] }
  puts "This is true!"
end
```

I know how the "any?" command works what i don't get is why **region[r]** resolves to **true** when the **r** value is "CA" - so we have **region["CA"]** giving us **true**!

I can see that "CA"["CA"] is true but why?  There is a little knowledge I am missing here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From String methods [] and slice, 
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/String.html#method-i-5B-5D

> ```
>     str[other_str] → new_str or nil
>     str.slice(other_str) → new_str or nil
>
> If a String is given, that string is returned if it occurs in str.
> ```

Comment: Cool. So I can actually have: if check[region] then puts "cool" end